# Zend Framework automatic modules routing

Tags: zend-framework

I have the following structure of my zend framework:

```
application/
    configs/
        application.ini
        routes.php
    layouts/
        scripts/
            includes/
            layout.phtml
    modules/
        somemodule1/
            controllers/
                IndexController.php
                ErrorController.php
            models/
            views/
                helpers/
                scripts/
                    error/
                        error.phtml
                    index/
                        index.phtml
            forms/
            Bootstrap.php
        somemodule2/
            controllers/
                IndexController.php
                ErrorController.php
            models/
            views/
                helpers/
                scripts/
                    error/
                        error.phtml
                    index/
                        index.phtml
            forms/
            Bootstrap.php

    Bootstrap.php
library/
    Zend/
    CustomClasses/
public/
    css/
    images/
    js/
    uploads/
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

Im trying to make it modular. For example I want to reach every module like this:
domain.com/modulename/controller/action/someotherparams. If I add new module, so it should load automatically without any changes to the routing class. What I already done is:

```
**routes.php**

protected function _initAutoloadModules()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
        array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/somemodule1'
        ), 
        array(
            'namespace' => 'Admin',
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/somemodule2'
        )            
      );
    return $autoloader;
}

**application.ini** 

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
appnamespace = "Default"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.frontController.defaultController = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.modules = ""
resources.view[] =
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
resources.session.use_only_cookies = on
includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
```

But actually its not working the way I want. Because I can't make the modules load automaticaly without changing the routes.php file (after new module was added to the system). So can anybody help me out?

Comment: How is routes.php called by your bootstrap? What is in your main application bootstrap and your module bootstrap classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you want to achive is default behavior from Zend Framework. Try it this way:

```
 $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader
    (
            array
            (
                'namespace' => '',
                'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
            )
        );
```

Do not forget to to use module prefix in controller name: Somemodule1_IndexController.